# Typescript this reference

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to rewrite a js react class file to tsx from scratch, but cannot even go through the constructor

I'm basically calling the Auth0 webAuth

```
export default class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
        clientID: '****************',
        domain: '******.eu.auth0.com',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/login`
      })
    }
```

But this just raises a

```
Property 'webAuth' does not exist on type 'Login'.
```

Funny thing is, according to Typescript doc, this should be the way to do so. I made sure to import auth0. What did I miss ? It `this` not the same in TS as in JS ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the **webAuth** property before you use it.

```js
export default class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, {}> {
    private webAuth: auth0.WebAuth;

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
        clientID: '****************',
        domain: '******.eu.auth0.com',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/login`
      })
    }
```

You can read more about classes in typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: Ok, so this error has nothing to do with the `this` element ? And do I have to define it in every function, or just once ? Because the function where I'm using `this.webAuth` raises `Cannot read property 'webAuth' of null`

Comment: class properties are defined once on the class. you should read a bit about typescript classes. :)